# почему не работает JS функция при событии onchange?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net

на `asp.net` странице есть чекбокс, я хочу чтобы при нажатии на него, срабатывал алерт, но вместо этого страница просто обновляется

Функция JS выглядит следующим образом:

```
    function check_AutoCampaign() {
      var chb = document.getElementById("<%=cbAutoCampaign.ClientID%>");
      if (chb.checked) {
          alert('checked');
      }
      else {
          alert('no it is not');
      }
      return false;
}
```

а вот и сам чекбокс:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbAutoCampaign" onchange="check_AutoCampaign();" runat="server" Text="chb" style="font-size: 10pt; margin-left: 5px" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

UPD:пробовал менять `AutoPostBack` на `False`, но это не решило мою проблему

Вопрос: почему страница обновляется, вместо того, чтобы показать алерт?

Comment: Не из-за этого ли `alert('no it's not');`? Замените на `alert("no it's not");`

Comment: нет, не из-за этого, то что внутри алерта я написал для примера (кстати поправил), т.е. там все ок

Comment: `AutoPostBack` поставьте в `false`

Comment: с этим параметром тоже игрался, но страница просто прекратила обновлятся, а алерт также не работал

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `preventDefault`.

Comment: а есть ли на странице элемент с таким id, как в этой строчке `document.getElementById("<%=cbAutoCampaign.ClientID%>"); `?

Comment: Может не стоит генерировать джаваскрипт?

Comment: Просто такой хардкод выглядит как костыль) а костыль == проблемы.

Comment: @srvr4vr Думаю стоит решить проблему тогда без джаваскрипта

Comment: @Дмытрык конечно есть

Comment: Во-первых, расскажите что именно вы хотите сделать

Comment: @srvr4vr если без JS, тогда думаю самописный алерт сделать, а если в условиях этого вопроса, то все просто, чтобы при нажатии и изменении чекбокса у меня показывался алерт от JS

Comment: А зачем вот поиск по ид вот это вот всё? все же можно проще сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так сделайте:

```
 function check_AutoCampaign(event) {

  if (event.target.checked) {
      alert('checked');
  }
  else {
      alert('no it is not');
  }
  return false;
}
```

В разметке тоже надо пробросить событие:

```
<asp:CheckBox onchange="check_AutoCampaign(event);" Text="chb" AutoPostBack="False" />
```